# Exponential distribution approximation

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

> Let $X_i$ be independent and identically distributed exponential with $\lambda = 2$  for $i = 1,\dotsc,10$. Estimate the probability $P(X_1 +···+ X_{10} > 3)$.

I tried to use the independent properties var$(x+y)=$ var$(x)+$var$(y)$ they are independent to find the mean is $0.5\cdot 10$ and the variance is $0.25\cdot 10$ 
so I am finding the $P(z>\frac{3-5}{\sqrt{2.5}})$ am I correct or the question is asking for something else?